# Prove: if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ then $f''(0)\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> let $f$ be a nonnegative and differentiable twice in the interval $[-1,1]$
>
> Prove: if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ then $f''(0)\geq 0$
>
> 1. Are all the assumptions on $f$ necessary for the result to hold ?
> 2. what can be said if $f''(0)= 0$ ?

Looking at the taylor polynomial and lagrange remainder we get:

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(c)x^2}{2}$$

$$f(x)=\frac{f''(c)x^2}{2}$$

Because the function is nonnegative and $\frac{x^2}{2}\geq 0$ so $f''(c)\geq 0$

For 1., all the data is needed but I can not find a valid reason.

For 2., can we conclude that the function the null function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is via the method of contradiction. Assume that $f''(0) < 0$. Then the function $f'$ is *strictly decreasing at $0$* which means that there is a neighborhood $I$ of $0$ such that if $x \in I, x < 0$ then $f'(x) > f'(0) = 0$ and if $x \in I, x > 0$ then $f'(x) < f'(0) = 0$. We can obviously choose $I$ of the form $(-h, h)$ and hence observing sign of $f'$ in $(-h, h)$ we see that $f$ is strictly increasing in $(-h, 0]$ and strictly decreasing in $[0, h]$ and since $f(0) = 0$ it follows that $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in I$ except $x = 0$. And this is contrary to the hypotheses that $f$ is non-negative. Thus we obtain the desired contradiction.

BTW the above argument can be replaced by the following concise argument. Since $f'(0) = 0, f''(0) < 0$ the point $0$ is a local strict maximum of $f$ and hence $f(x) < f(0) = 0$ for all $x$ in some neighborhood of $I$ of $0$ except $x = 0$. And this contradicts that $f$ is non-negative.

The argument in first paragraph actually shows how the vanishing of derivative and sign of second derivative guarantee local maxima/minima and if the reader is well aware of the proof of second derivative test for maxima/minima, it is preferable to adopt the argument in second paragraph.

---

As can be seen from the arguments above we don't need continuity of $f''$. And we can avoid difficult theorems like Taylor or L'Hospital. The argument used in first paragraph leads to [one of the simpler proofs of Taylor's Theorem with Peano's form of remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809307/72031).

**Update**: The condition $f' (0)=0$ is superfluous here. The function is non-negative and $f(0)=0$ and hence $0$ is a point of local minima so that $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is enough when $f''$ is continuous.

---

Here's a way without the continuity assumption.

This Taylor expansion $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0) + o(x^2)$ yields here: $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0) + o(x^2)$$

Either $f''(0)=0$ and we're good, otherwise the previous equality rewrites as 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2f(x)}{f''(0) x^2}= 1$

Consequently, $f(x)$ and $f''(0) x^2$ must share the same sign on a neighborhood of $0$.

Since $f\geq 0$ and $x^2\geq 0$ that implies $f''(0)\geq 0$

---

When $f''(0)=0$, $f(x)=o(x^2)$. I don't see anything more you could say.

Comment: This works, so +1.  You might consider referencing the Peano form of the remainder here.  -Mark

Comment: The Lagrange remainder in Taylor's formula is still valid if $f$ is twice differentiable but not $C^2$, due to the Darboux property of derivatives.

Comment: How did you get to $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2f(x)}{f''(0) x^2}= 1$?

Comment: @gbox that's the very definition of $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0) + o(x^2)$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM it is the definition of Peano form? if we plug the limit to 2f(x) do not the limit should be $0$?

Comment: @gbox $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0) + o(x^2)$ is Peano Form. But in general, $f(x) = o(g(x)) \iff \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM In your last comment, $f=o(g)$ if and only if $\frac{f}{g}\to 0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, typo. What I mean is $f(x) = o(g(x)) \iff \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 0$ by definition and therefore $f(x) = g(x) + o(g(x)) \iff \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$

Answer (score 2):

For 2) you could have $f(x)=x^4$ which satisfies all properties and conclusions including $f''(0)=0$, yet $f(x)$ is not identically zero.

For 1) relaxing the condition that $f(0)=0$, we could look at $f(x)=\cos(x)+3$ (which has instead $f(0)=4$).  It satisfies the property that $f(x)$ is non-negative, is twice differentiable on $[-1,1]$ and that $f'(0)=0$.  However, $f''(0)=-\cos(0)=-1$ is not non-negative.

Relaxing the condition that $f(x)$ be non-negative on the interval, letting $f(x)=-x^2$ one has $f(0)=0, f'(0)=0$, yet $f''(0)=-2$ is not non-negative

Relaxing the condition that $f$ be twice differentiable makes no sense since then $f''(0)$ can't be talked about.

Try searching yourself as well for a function $f(x)$ which violates only the hypothesis that $f'(0)=0$ which has $f''(0)<0$.

With these counterexamples, we conclude that in fact every hypothesis was necessary.

Comment: $x^3$ is not nonnegative on the interval. Use $x^4$ instead.

Comment: @Mosquite thanks.  I moved one degree up from $x^2$ to fix that $f''(0)=0$ and forgot to account for that.

Comment: But are the hypotheses sufficient to guarantee that $f''(0)\ge 0$?

Comment: @Dr.MV I interpreted his question as asking about the after thought questions (*were all in fact necessary or could any hypotheses be dropped, and can you conclude if $f''(x)=0$ that $f(x)=0$*).  His proof seemed sufficient to me, but LaGrandDODOM points out in his answer that the continuity of $f''(x)$ was tacitly assumed in the OP's proof, and can be dropped as well.  I see no reason to replicate LaGrandDODOM's proof at this point or to come up with my own.

Comment: The OP's "proof" only shows that $f''(c)\ge 0$, for some $c\in (0,x)$, ]but does not prove that indeed $f''(0)\ge 0$. And yes, you're correct, using the Peano form for the remainder is one very straightway forward.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

The continuity of $f''$ [is not really needed](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/) to apply Taylor's formula with the Lagrange remainder. Anyway, we may just apply [l'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to get:
$$ f''(0) =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x} = 2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}. $$
Since both $f(x)$ and $x^2$ are non-negative over $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$, $\;f''(0)\geq 0$ readily follows.
Obviously we cannot deduce the strict inequality $f''(0)>0$, as shown by $f(x)=x^4$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I think it is better to apply L'Hospital once to get $$2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x} = f''(0) \text{ (by defn of }f''(0))$$ This works without continuity of $f''$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: thanks, updated.

Comment: @Dr.MV: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/

Comment: Thaks for link to Gowers blog post. It is indeed a very good post. BTW proof of Taylor's theorem with Peano remainder given by Gowers is essentially the same as the one I linked in my answer.