# A demonstration of Lagrange's Form for the Remainder of a Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, math-history

The following argument for Lagrange's Form for the Remainder of a Taylor polynomial is a typical one in analysis books.  Even in the case of finding the remainder when the Taylor polynomial is a linear polynomial, deciding on the functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ is not apparent.  (See the following argument.)  Can someone provide the motivation for these functions?  Also, does anyone know who concocted this argument?

**Lagrange's Form for the Remainder**

$f$ is a twice differentiable function defined on an interval $I$, and $a$ is an element in $I$ distinct from any endpoints of $I$. For every real number $x \in I$ distinct from $a$, there is a real number $c$ between $a$ and $x$ such that
\begin{equation*}
R_{1}(x) = \frac{f^{(2)}(c)}{2!} \, (x - a)^{2} .
\end{equation*}
So, if $T_{1}$ denotes the linear Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$,
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = T_{1}(x) + \frac{f^{(2)}(c)}{2!} \, (x - a)^{2} .
\end{equation*}

**Demonstration**
\begin{equation*}
g(u) = f(x) - \Bigl[f(u) + f^{\prime}(u)(x - u)\Bigr]
\end{equation*}
is a differentiable, and
\begin{equation*}
g^{\prime}(u) = - f^{\prime\prime}(u)(x - u) .
\end{equation*}
The function
\begin{equation*}
h(u) = g(u) - g(a) \left(\frac{1}{x - a}\right)^{2} (x - u)^{2}
\end{equation*}
is a also differentiable, and
\begin{equation*}
h^{\prime}(u) = - f^{\prime\prime}(u)(x - u) + 2g(a) \left(\frac{1}{x - a}\right)^{2} (x - u) .
\end{equation*}
Moreover, $h(x) = g(x) = 0$, and $h(a) = 0$. According to Rolle's Theorem, there is a real number $a < c < x$ such that $h^{\prime}(c) = 0$.
\begin{equation*}
0 = h^{\prime}(c)
= - f^{\prime\prime}(c)(x - c) + 2g(a) \left(\frac{1}{x - a}\right)^{2} (x - c) ,
\end{equation*}
or equivalently, since $x \neq c$ and since
\begin{equation*}
g(a) = f(x) - \Bigl[f(a) + f^{\prime}(a)(x - a)\Bigr] ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
f(x) - \Bigl[f(a) + f^{\prime}(a)(x - a)\Bigr] = \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(c)}{2!} \, (x - a)^{2} .
\end{equation*}

Comment: Egads, that looks unintuitive. So much easier if you assume $f$ is $C^2.$

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the historical perspective on Taylor's series so I can't say "who concocted this argument". But I can provide an intuitive justification for the technique used in the proof of Taylor's Theorem.

First of all note that the Taylor's theorem main goal is to express the function $f(x)$ as a power series in powers of $(x - a)$ where $a$ is a suitable point where $f$ behaves in a *very good manner*. By *good manner* we mean here that the the function $f$ has derivatives upto a certain order in the neighborhood of the point $a$. Thus if we assume $$f(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}(x - a) + a_{2}(x - a)^{2} + \cdots$$ and assume that the series above can be differentiated repeatedly then we get the coefficients as $$a_{n} = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$ Thus if $f$ is differentiable $n$ times in the neighborhood of $a$ we can consider the Taylor polynomial $$T_{n}(x, a) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \cdots + \frac{f^{(n - 1)}(a)}{(n - 1)!}(x - a)^{n - 1}$$ and our hope is that this Taylor polynomial is a good approximation of $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of $a$. And the error in approximation is $$R_{n}(x, a) = f(x) - T_{n}(x, a)$$ Finding an explicit expression of $R_{n}(x, a)$ in terms of $f, n, a, x$ is the real crux of Taylor's Theorem.

And yes this part is tricky. Suppose we used the Taylor polynomial $T_{n + 1}(x)$ instead of $T_{n}(x)$. The difference between $T_{n}$ and $T_{n + 1}$ is the extra term of type $a_{n}(x - a)^{n}$. Since we actually don't use $T_{n + 1}$ but rather $T_{n}$ so the expectation is that the Remainder should behave almost like the extra term $a_{n}(x - a)^{n}$ and hence it makes sense to analyze the express $$\frac{R_{n}(x, a)}{(x - a)^{n}}$$ The tricky part now is to fix the variable $x$ in the above expression and consider it as a function $a$. And then we change the notation slightly to $$\frac{R_{n}(x, u)}{(x - u)^{n}}$$ where $u$ lies between $a$ and $x$ and compare this error with maximum error $$\frac{R_{n}(x, a)}{(x - a)^{n}}$$ and thus our final function is $$g(u) = \frac{R_{n}(x, u)}{(x - u)^{n}} - \frac{R_{n}(x, a)}{(x - a)^{n}}$$ and we want to get rid of $(x - u)^{n}$ in denominator (to simplify calculation) so we instead use the function $$F(u) = (x - u)^{n}g(u) = R_{n}(x, u) - \left(\frac{x - u}{x - a}\right)^{n}R_{n}(x, a)$$ Doing this achieves the important goal $F(a) = F(x) = 0$ so that we can apply Rolle's Theorem to get $F'(c) = 0$ for some $c$ between $a, x$. The expression for $F'(u)$ contains the expression $R_{n}(x, a)$ and the equation $F'(c) = 0$ allows us to expression $R_{n}(x, a)$ in terms of $x, n, a$ (although this is somewhat indeterminate because the exact value of $c$ is not known).

---

Above technique is based on differential calculus. There is another simpler way to look at it if we use integration. The expression $R_{n}(x, a)$ seen as a function of $x$ is such that all its derivatives upto order $(n - 1)$ vanish at $x = a$ and $R_{n}^{(n)}(x, a) = f^{(n)}(x)$. Thus $R_{n}(x, a)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ anti-derivative of $f^{(n)}(x)$ and moreover its first $(n - 1)$ derivatives vanish at $x = a$. Under these circumstances it is easy to prove via integration by parts (and induction on $n$) that $$R_{n}(x, a) = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!}\int_{a}^{x}(x - t)^{n - 1}f^{(n)}(t)\,dt$$ Putting $t = x + (a - x)u$ we get $$R_{n}(x, a) = \frac{(x - a)^{n}}{(n - 1)!}\int_{0}^{1}u^{n - 1}f^{(n)}(x + (a - x)u)\,du$$ The integral can be approximated using mean value theorems for integrals to get $$R_{n}(x, a) = \frac{(x - a)^{n}}{(n - 1)!}f^{(n)}(c)\int_{0}^{1}u^{n - 1}\,du$$ i.e. $$R_{n}(x, a) = \frac{(x - a)^{n}}{n!}f^{(n)}(c)$$ where $c$ is some point between $a$ and $x$.

Both the approaches can be modified in a simple manner to give rise to Cauchy's form of remainder. Also note that the approach based on differential calculus assumes that $f^{(n)}(x)$ exists in some neighborhood of $a$ whereas the approach based on integration requires that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is continuous on some neighborhood of $a$. There is another form of remainder for Taylor series which goes by the name of [Peano's form of remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031) and this requires a totally different approach for its proof.

Comment: I appreciate your reply.  I agree that it is intuitive to assume that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and take the difference between $T_{n+1}$ and $T_{n}$, which is $a_{n}(x - a)^{n}$.  I agree that $R_{n}(x,a)$ should be "like" $(x - a)^{n}$.  A way to "measure" the "likeness" is by taking the quotient of them and showing it is close to 1.  I may look at the difference and show it is close to 0, but if that didn't lead to the Lagrange's Form for the remainder, I can see looking at the quotient.

Comment: You say that the next thing to do is to "fix the variable $x$ in the above expression and consider it as a function $a$."  This is as contrived as the definition of $g(u)$ in the demonstration that I provided.  Right?

Comment: @user74973: I have to agree that the proof technique is somewhat contrived. Note that the traditional proof (especially in old books) deals with $R_{n}(b, a)$ so that the variable $x$ is already replaced by a constant $b$ and the function $f$ is analyzed in interval $[a, b]$ rather than in neighborhood of $a$. And then the replaces $a$ with variable $u$ and proceeds in the manner explained.

Comment: @user74973: personally I find the proof via integration much more satisfying because it gives a direct formula (in terms of an integral) for the error $R_{n}(x, a)$.

Comment: Yes, older textbooks give expansions of a function into a Taylor polynomial about $a$ evaluated at another constant $b$.  Unfortunately, the ones I have seen don't give any explanation for what motivated them to look at $g(u)$, which is a Taylor  polynomial about some arbitrary number $u$ evaluated at $a$.  My suspicion is that some clever mathematician writing a Calculus textbook wanted to include Taylor polynomials right after linearization.  That is why I included "History of Mathematics" in the tags.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of Lagrange's form for the remainder using integration by parts.  I am definitely going to include that in my notes!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The $\underline{motivation}$ comes from repeatedly integration by parts of the following identity:
>   $$
> \mrm{f}\pars{x} =
> \mrm{f}\pars{0} + \int_{0}^{x}\mrm{f}'\pars{x - t}\,\dd t
> $$

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & =
\mrm{f}\pars{0} + \int_{0}^{x}\mrm{f}'\pars{t}\,\dd t =
\mrm{f}\pars{0} + \int_{0}^{x}\mrm{f}'\pars{x - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{f}\pars{0} + \mrm{f}'\pars{0}x + \int_{0}^{x}t\,\mrm{f}''\pars{x - t}
\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{f}\pars{0} + \mrm{f}'\pars{0}x + \half\,\mrm{f}''\pars{0}x^{2} + \half\int_{0}^{x}t^{2}\,\mrm{f}'''\pars{x - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{f}\pars{0} + \mrm{f}'\pars{0}x + \half\,\mrm{f}''\pars{0}x^{2} +
{1 \over 3 \times 2}\,\mrm{f}'''\pars{0}x^{3} +
{1 \over 3 \times 2}
\int_{0}^{x}t^{3}\,\mrm{f}^{\pars{\texttt{IV}}}\pars{x - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & = \cdots =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\mrm{f}^{\pars{n}}\pars{0} \over n!}\,x^{n} +
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}t^{n}\,\mrm{f}^{\pars{n + 1}}\pars{x - t}\,\dd t
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, Paramanand Singh also offered this argument as much preferable.  I am not disputing that.  There is this other argument - the one I provided in the post - that involves only differentiation and Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem.  What motivated the definitions for the functions $g(u)$ and $h(u)$?

Comment: @user74973 Thanks for your remark. I was aware of that. However, I wanted to show the simplest and straightforward way such that it can be helpful for newbies.

I remember that your way was more or less my first Taylor encounter when I was in the undergraduate school ( a looooong time ago !!! ). Thanks.

Comment: I think the argument that I provided in the post was the first that I had seen in an analysis class - also a loooong time ago.  Ha! Ha!  This was not the original demonstration for Lagrange's form for the remainder, though.  Cauchy provided that.  I put the tag "Math-History" on the post - I thought this would have been an easy question for someone knowledgeable in the history of mathematics.

Comment: @user74973 History is not in my baggage but I consider it quite interesting. What we get is a lot of isolated pieces. But, there are science historians who are deeply dedicated to clarify many situations such as you already pointed out. From now on, I'll visit more frequently the $\texttt{math-history}$ tag. Thanks.

Comment: I once had a Latin-to-English translation of Brook Taylor's Methodus Incrementorum Directa et Inversa.  I got it as part of a dissertation that someone had written as part of their doctoral degree.  Yes, there are serious historians of mathematics, and they are mathematically inclined.  (I am surprised that none of them responded.)

Comment: I am not familiar with this website.  How do you specifically look at posts with the `math-history` tag?

Comment: @user74973 At the top of this page ( MSE site ) click on the link TAGS.

Comment: I will tell you if anyone responds with a historical account for this argument.