# Can a Taylor polynomial of a function around a certain value yield different polynomials?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Say we want to find the Taylor polynomial of order $2$ for $\sqrt{2+x}$ around $x = 10$.

Simply plugging in the numbers for a Taylor sum $\sum \dfrac{f^k(10)(x - 10)^k}{k!} $ with $n = 2$ then gives us a polynomial approximation of $\sqrt{2+x}$.
Is it possible to give a *different* polynomial expansion than the one from the formula of $\sqrt{2+x}$ of order $2$ around $x = 10$? I personally don't understand how a different polynomial expression with the same order around the same $x$ is to be found. However, the problem I've found asks this precise question.

(Sorry for poor formatting)

Comment: The point, I think, is that the Taylor series of a function at a point is unique.

Comment: Look here for the proof of uniqueness https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923624/taylors-polynomial-uniqueness-proof-why-are-these-limits-inferable

Comment: @KafkaBoi Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor polynomial of order $2$ of the function $f(x):=\sqrt{2+x}$ is the *unique polynomial* $j_2$ of degree $\leq 2$ satisfying
$$f(10+t)-j_2(t)= o(t^2)\qquad (t\to0)\ .$$
It gives a good approximation to the function value $f(x)$ when $x=10+t$ is near $10$, and the quality of this approximation increases tremendously as $t\to0$.

But, depending on your purpose, there are other polynomials of degree $\leq2$ approximating $f$ very well in the neighborhood of $x=10$, e.g. the polynomial
$$h(x):=1.71446 + 0.205225 x - 0.00302609 x^2\ .$$
The following figure shows that that the maximal errror of $h$ in the $x$-interval $[8,12]$ is much smaller than the error of $j_2$.

[image]