# (Why) does the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ (seems to) converge for $x\in (-1,0)$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, approximation

By Taylor's theorem, $$\ln(x+1) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j+1}\frac{x^j} n + \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}(1+c)^{-(n+1)}x^{n+1},$$ for some $c\in (0,x)$. It's easy to see that the second term tends to $0$ as $n$ increases when $x\in [0,1]$. It's also easy to see that it diverges to infinity when $x>1$. For $x\in (-1,0)$, it's not clear whether it gets small or not. Trying out some values, it seems like the error does tend to $0$, but I don't see how to prove this. Taylor's theorem doesn't seem to help here as the second term could be arbitrarily big for some $c$'s in $(0,x)$.

Why does (if it indeed does) this approximation work for $x\in (-1,0)$ and can I get some hint on how to prove this?

Note: I use the notation $(a,b)$ with $a>b$ to mean $(b,a) = \{x: b<x<a\}$.

Comment: Do you know what Radius of Convergence is? And how to find it (ratio test)?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to use a simpler infinite, not discrete like here,  series?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, this can be used to prove that the series converges to something for $x\in (-1,0)$. But how do i know whether that something is $\ln(x+1)$?

Comment: You know because of [Uniqueness of Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923624/taylors-polynomial-uniqueness-proof-why-are-these-limits-inferable). If a Taylor series converges at all, it must converge to the function it is a Taylor series of.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/878374/42969.

Comment: @K.defaoite That's not true, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#The_function_is_not_analytic).