# Twice differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

While reading in Wikipedia ([Derivative # Higher derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Higher_derivatives)) I encountered this definition:
[image]

- I don't understand why $f(x+h)$ equals to the expression in the right side (where is this come from?).
- Plus, how did they get to the limit expression? Have they moved the right side to the left and divide by $h^2$? I'm having trouble seeing the logic behind it.
- In addition, can I turn the last expression within the limit to an expression without $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ - I mean, to remain only with $f(x)$?
- Lastly, if a function has the limit above does it mean it is twice differentiable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is Taylor expansion built at $h=0$.

Comment: That is not a definition.but rather an implication of Taylor's series for the function $f$ at $x$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031