# Existence of second derivative implies symmetric second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I would like to know if the following statement is true.

> Let $f:(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such $f'$
>   exits for all $x \in (a,b)$ and also exists $f''(x_0)$ for some
>   $a<x_0<b$. Then
>
> $ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-2f(x_0)+f(x_0-h)}{h^2} = f''(x_0)$.

**Obs:** I'm **not** assuming that $f'$ is continuos in some neighborhood of $x_0$. However, I think that requirement of the existence of $f'$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ is a necessity for the existence of $f''(x_0)$.

Comment: You can check my proof if it were correct. I don't make use of the continuity of $f'$.

Comment: Your observations at the end are correct. And yes the result in question is true. A simple proof is possible via L'Hospital's Rule or [Taylor's theorem with Peano's form of remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031).

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor's formula,
$$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + hf'(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x_0) + o(h^2)$$
and 
$$f(x_0 - h) = f(x_0) - hf'(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x_0) + o(h^2)$$
as $h \to 0$.
This shows that the expression whose limit you are to compute is equal to $f''(x_0) + o(1)$.

Comment: Could you give a reference for the Taylor's theorem with its hypothesis. In every reference I looked, they always assume that $f'$ is continuos in some neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: @Diego: That particular version of Taylor's theorem is not very popular. You may have a look at the link I gave in the comment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varphi(t)=f(x_{0}+th)-2f(x_{0})-f(x_{0}-(1-t)h)$, $0\leq t\leq 1$, then $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\varphi'(c_{h})$ for some $0<c_{h}<1$, so $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=[f'(x_{0}+c_{h}h)-f'(x_{0}-(1-c_{h})h)]h$. For $\epsilon>0$, find some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|u|<\delta$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f'(x_{0}+u)-f'(x_{0})}{u}-f''(x_{0})\right|<\epsilon/2.
\end{align*}
Now for $0<|h|<\delta$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{h^{2}}[\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)]-f''(x_{0})\right|&\leq\left|\frac{f'(x_{0}+c_{h}h)-f'(x_{0})}{h}-c_{h}f''(x_{0})\right|\\
&~~~~+\left|\frac{f'(x_{0}-(1-c_{h})h)-f'(x_{0})}{-h}-(1-c_{h})f''(x_{0})\right|\\
&\leq|c_{h}|\left|\frac{f'(x_{0}+c_{h}h)-f'(x_{0})}{c_{h}{h}}-f''(x_{0})\right|\\
&~~~~+|1-c_{h}|\left|\frac{f'(x_{0}-(1-c_{h})h)-f'(x_{0})}{-(1-c_{h})h}-f''(x_{0})\right|\\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=f(x_{0}+h)-2f(x_{0})+f(x_{0}-h)$.

Comment: This is a nice and novel proof for me. It does look a bit complicated because of $c_h$ (lot of $h$ in the equations) and you could have just used $c$ instead. But showing the dependence of $c$ on $h$ explicitly does not leave any room for confusion. +1

Comment: Minor nitpick. Using $\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon/2$ in the beginning also leads to $c_h\epsilon+(1-c_h)\epsilon=\epsilon$ at the end.

Comment: Okay, that is clearer, thanks.