# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 18: Use Taylor's Theorem to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

The following is a problem from Spivak's *Calculus*

> **Chapter 20, Problem 18**: Deduce Theorem $1$ as a corollary of Taylor's
> Theorem, with any form of the remainder. (The catch is that it will be
> necessary to assume one more derivative than in the hypotheses for
> Theorem 1).

Here is Theorem $1$

> **Theorem 1** Suppose that $f$ is a function for which
>
> $$f'(a),...,f^{(n)}(a)$$
>
> all exist. Let
>
> $$a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}, 0\leq k\leq n$$
>
> and define
>
> $$P_{n,a}(x)=a_0+a_1(x-a)+...+a_n(x-a)^n$$
>
> Then
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$$

and here is Taylor's Theorem

> **Theorem 4 (Taylor's Theorem)** Suppose that $f',...,f^{(n+1)}$ are defined on $[a,x]$, and that $R_{n,a}(x)$ is defined by
>
> $$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+R_{n,a}(x)$$
>
> Then
>
> $$R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1},\text{ for some }
>  t \text{ in } (a,x)$$
>
> (Lagrange form of the remainder).

**My primary question is: why can or can't we use the following proof**

> Assume we know Taylor's theorem is true and assume the first $n+1$
> derivatives of $f$ exist on $[a,x]$.
>
> Taylor's theorem tells us that
>
> $$f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)=R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1},
>  \text{ for } t\in (a,x)$$
>
> Then,
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}
>  \frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}
>  \frac{f^{(n+1)(t)}}{(n+1)!}(x-a)=0$$

In addition, let me just show the solution manual solution and my own understanding of it in more steps

**Solution Manual**

> Suppose $|f^{(n+1)}|$ is bounded, by some $M$, on some interval around
> $a$. Then for $x$ in this interval we have
>
> $$|R_{n,a}(x)|=\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(t)|}{n!}|x-a|^{n+1}\tag{1}$$
>
> so
>
> $$\frac{|R_{n,a}(x)|}{|x-a|^n}\leq M|x-a|\tag{2}$$
>
> so
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{R_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0\tag{3}$$
>
> A similar proof works for the integral form of the remainder and for
> the Cauchy form.

**Here is my understanding of this proof in more steps**

> Suppose we know Taylor's theorem is true, and assume the assumptions
> of that theorem are true on some interval $[a,x]$.
>
> One of those assumptions is that $f',...,f^{(n+1)}$ are defined on
> $[a,x]$. Thus, $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous on $[a,x]$, and
> hence bounded on this interval.
>
> Thus, there exists some $M>0$, such that for any $x_1\in[a,x]$ we
> have $|f^{(n+1)}(x_1)|\leq M$.
>
> In addition, Taylor's theorem tells us that there is some $t\in
>  (a,x)$ such that
>
> $$R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}\tag{4}$$
>
> **Second question:** why does $(1)$ have the denominator as $n!$ and not $(n+1)!$ as in $(4)$?
>
> Now we take the absolute value of both sides of $(4)$
>
> $$|R_{n,a}(x)|=\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(t)|}{(n+1)!}|(x-a)|^{n+1}$$
>
> $$0\leq \frac{|R_{n,a}(x)|}{|x-a|^{n}}=\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(t)|}{(n+1)!}|x-a|$$
>
> $$\leq \frac{M}{(n+1)!}|x-a|\leq M|x-a|$$
>
> Hence
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}
>  \frac{|R_{n,a}(x)|}{|x-a|^{n}}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}
>  \frac{|f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)|}{|x-a|^{n}} =0$$
>
> $$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^{n}} =0$$
>
> which is the result of Theorem 1.

Comment: It is easier to apply L Hospital Rule to prove theorem 1 directly rather than using extra hypotheses of Taylor theorem.

Comment: When Theorem 1 is introduced it is proved with L'Hopital's Rule. The problems look at alternative ways of proving the theorem.

Comment: For an alternative approach do have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031

Answer (score 1):

For your second question: yes I think it is a typo, and it should be $(n+1)!$.

For your first question: note that the $t$ depends on $x$, the $f^{(n+1)}(t)$ term will vary as $x \to a$ (you cannot treat it as a constant in $x$), and you cannot immediately conclude $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!} (x-a) = 0$. As the solution manual shows, this can be fixed as long as you have a condition that ensures the existence of some $M$ such that $|f^{(n+1)}(t)| \le M$ for all $x$ near $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, regarding your paragraph where you express your understanding, I would note that just because $f^{(n+1)}$ is defined on a closed interval **DOES NOT** imply that $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous on that same interval. The classic counter example is: $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$. $f'$ is defined on $[-c,c]$ but is **NOT** continuous on $[-c,c]$ because $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) \text{ DNE}$ (which means that $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$ by definition).

Secondly, just to add some detail to concretize *angryavian*'s response, consider the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$. This derivative is defined on $[0,c]$ but is *not* bounded. This is why Spivak *assumes* boundedness in his proof.