$\lim_{x \to 0} (\ln^2(x) \cdot (e^x+x^2-x-1))$
How I tried it :
$\lim_{x \to 0} (\ln^2(x) \cdot (e^x+x^2-x-1)) = \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{(e^x+x^2-x-1)}
{\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}})$ this limit is in Indeterminate form and bt using L'Hôpital's rule we get
$\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(e^x+x^2-x-1)}
{\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)})})= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x+2x-1}{-\frac{2}{x \ln ^3(x)}
}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \ln^3(x)(e^x+2x-1}{-2} $ which leads to nowhere.
Any help would be appreciated !
EDIT
I tried to use the fact that
$$(\ln^2(x) \cdot (e^x+x^2-x-1))
 = x\ln^2(x) \cdot \left({\frac{e^x-1}{x}}\right)+x^2\ln^2(x)-x\ln^2(x) $$
that becomes
$$x\ln^2(x) \cdot \left (\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x} \right) +x-1 \right)$$
Then let $t=\left (\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x} \right) +x-1 \right)$ when $x \to0^+ \implies t \to 0^+$
So now we just have to evaluate the limit of $u=x\ln^2(x) $ whejn $x \to 0^+$
which is $0^+ \times + \infty = + \infty$
Then the original limit is of the form $0^+ \times +\infty$
so we write is as
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{ (e^x+x^2-x-1)}{\frac{1}{x\ln^2(x)}}\right)$$
using L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{ (e^x+2x-1)}{\frac{\ln(x)+1}{x^2 \ln^2(x)}}\right)= \lim_{x\to0^+} \left (  \frac{(e^x+2x-1)x^2 \ln^2(x)}{\ln(x)+1}\right )$$
What am I supposed to do after ? Or did I even use that information correctly?

Where is this coming from? Shouldn't this be a right-handed limit?

@Vasili It's from a highschool level exam . Well $\ln(x) $ has a domain of $(0, + \infty)$ So yes $\lim_{x \to 0} $ is the same as $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$ in this case

Do you know Taylor series? Not sure this is a high-school level question.

Yes, but we do not learn them in school here so I think there has to be another way, I tried multiplying and deviding by $x$  and $x^2$ and I think I got somewhere but still was not able to finish it

Try using the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ first to simplify the expression in parentheses to $\frac{3}{2}x^2 + o(x^2)$. So it suffices to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\ln x)^2x^2$, which by L'Hôpital's rule is:

 \begin{align*}\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{(\ln x)^2}{1/x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{2\ln x \times \frac{1}{x}}{-2x^{-3}} = -\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{x^{-2}} = -\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-2x^{-3}} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^2 = 0.   \end{align*}

A cleverer way to get $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\ln x)^2x^2$ is applying the algebra of the limit operator, which enables you to just evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+}x\ln x$.  This limit is more widely known.

Thanks, that seems interesting. Can you please explain how we got from $1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6} + ....+ x^2 -x -1$  to $\frac{3}{2} x^2 +o(x^2)$ please

@AntonyTheo "$o(x^2)$" is called the Peano's remainder.  Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809293/taylors-theorem-with-peanos-form-of-remainder for more details.

Hint
$$(\ln^2(x) \cdot (e^x+x^2-x-1))
 = x\ln^2(x) \cdot \left({\frac{e^x-1}{x}}\right)+x^2\ln^2(x)-x\ln^2(x) $$

I tried using that but got even more lost, could you check my edited post please.

$\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln(x)=0  \\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1 \\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\ln^2(x)=0\  \lim_{x\to 0}x\ln^2(x)=0$
